# Biblatex: conjunction translation in \parencite, \cite and \textcite

Tags: biblatex, babel

I am using Biblatex and Babel.
I am trying to print a translated conjunction for `\parencite`, `\cite` and `\textcite` depending on the language I provide with `langid`. For reasons too long to explain, I can't define a specific `style=` for the biblatex package.

This is the document which I'm testing on:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, allcolors=blue]{hyperref}

\usepackage[english, main=italian, german]{babel}
\selectlanguage{italian}

\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes} 
\setquotestyle{english} 

\usepackage[backend=biber,
natbib=true,
citestyle=authoryear-icomp,
bibstyle=authoryear-icomp,
ibidpage=true,
dashed=true,
pagetracker=false,
maxbibnames=4,
maxcitenames=2,
autolang=other
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{sample.bib}

\DeclareQuoteStyle{english}%
    {\textquotedblleft}
    [\textquotedblleft]
    {\textquotedblright}
        [0.05em]
    {\textquoteleft}
    [\textquoteleft]
    {\textquoteright}
\DeclareQuoteStyle{german}%
    {\textquotedblleft}
    [\textquotedblleft]
    {\textquotedblright}
        [0.05em]
    {\textquoteleft}
    [\textquoteleft]
    {\textquoteright}
\DeclareQuoteStyle{italian}%
    {\textquotedblleft}
    [\textquotedblleft]
    {\textquotedblright}
        [0.05em]
    {\textquoteleft}
    [\textquoteleft]
    {\textquoteright}

\begin{document}
\section{Tutorial LaTeX}

\lipsum[1-4]

\parencite{greenwade93} \cite{greenwade93} \textcite{greenwade93}

\parencite{gurlami1943} \cite{gurlami1943} \textcite{gurlami1943}

\parencite{landa1943} \cite{landa1943} \textcite{landa1943}


\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc, title={Bibliografia}]
\nocite{*}

\end{document}
```

Considering these three bib-entries, whose language I have clearly differentiated ...

```
@article{greenwade93,
    author  = "George Greenwade and Bob Jordan",
    title   = "The {C}omprehensive {T}ex {A}rchive {N}etwork ({CTAN})",
    year    = "1993",
    journal = "TUGBoat",
    volume  = "14",
    number  = "3",
    pages   = "342-351",
    langid = "english",
}

@article{gurlami1943,
    author  = "Enzo Gurlami and Dominic DeCocco",
    title   = "How to sneak into parties",
    year    = "1943",
    journal = "Scalps",
    volume  = "14",
    number  = "3",
    pages   = "342-351",
    langid = "italian",
}

@article{landa1943,
    author  = "Hans Landa and King Schultz",
    title   = "How to be an actor",
    year    = "1943",
    journal = "The Hateful Eight",
    volume  = "14",
    number  = "3",
    pages   = "100-3901",
    langid = "german",
}
```

... the result is the same -- the conjunction used is always the italian one "e":
[image: Why]

If I try fixing the problem by myself, the result is disgusting and every conjunction is added*, regardless of the language defined (*even in the bibliography, which is something I don't need). What am I doing wrong?

```
\DeclareDelimFormat{finalnamedelim}{%
  \ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{2}{\finalandcomma}{}%
  \iffieldannotation{langid}{english}{\addspace\printtext{and}\space}{}%
  \iffieldannotation{langid}{italian}{\addspace\printtext{e}\space}{}%
  \iffieldannotation{langid}{german}{\addspace\printtext{und}\space}{}%
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I'm not sure if I like that, after all the text is in italian, but this here should work

```
\DeclareNameWrapperFormat{labelname}{%
  \iffieldundef{langid}{#1}{\foreignlanguage[captions]{\thefield{langid}}{#1}}}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

With the default settings `autolang` only applies to the bibliography whereas the `\cite` commands are typeset in the surrounding language. You can use the `language` option (whose default is `autobib`) to typeset both bibliography entries and citations in the language of the cited work (set `language=auto,`). Note that this affects more than just the "and": It changes the entire localisation, so in the example it also affects "ibid.".

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, allcolors=blue]{hyperref}

\usepackage[english, main=italian, german]{babel}
\selectlanguage{italian}

\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes} 
\setquotestyle{english} 

\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  natbib=true,
  style=authoryear-icomp,
  ibidpage=true,
  dashed=true,
  pagetracker=false,
  maxbibnames=4,
  maxcitenames=2,
  language=auto,
  autolang=other,
]{biblatex}


\DeclareQuoteStyle{english}%
    {\textquotedblleft}
    [\textquotedblleft]
    {\textquotedblright}
        [0.05em]
    {\textquoteleft}
    [\textquoteleft]
    {\textquoteright}
\DeclareQuoteStyle{german}%
    {\textquotedblleft}
    [\textquotedblleft]
    {\textquotedblright}
        [0.05em]
    {\textquoteleft}
    [\textquoteleft]
    {\textquoteright}
\DeclareQuoteStyle{italian}%
    {\textquotedblleft}
    [\textquotedblleft]
    {\textquotedblright}
        [0.05em]
    {\textquoteleft}
    [\textquoteleft]
    {\textquoteright}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{greenwade93,
    author  = "George Greenwade and Bob Jordan",
    title   = "The {C}omprehensive {T}ex {A}rchive {N}etwork ({CTAN})",
    year    = "1993",
    journal = "TUGBoat",
    volume  = "14",
    number  = "3",
    pages   = "342-351",
    langid = "english",
}
@article{gurlami1943,
    author  = "Enzo Gurlami and Dominic DeCocco",
    title   = "How to sneak into parties",
    year    = "1943",
    journal = "Scalps",
    volume  = "14",
    number  = "3",
    pages   = "342-351",
    langid = "italian",
}
@article{landa1943,
    author  = "Hans Landa and King Schultz",
    title   = "How to be an actor",
    year    = "1943",
    journal = "The Hateful Eight",
    volume  = "14",
    number  = "3",
    pages   = "100-3901",
    langid = "german",
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\section{Tutorial LaTeX}

\lipsum[1-4]

\parencite{greenwade93} \cite{greenwade93} \textcite{greenwade93}

\parencite{gurlami1943} \cite{gurlami1943} \textcite{gurlami1943}

\parencite{landa1943} \cite{landa1943} \textcite{landa1943}


\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc, title={Bibliografia}]
\nocite{*}

\end{document}
```

[image: (Greenwade and Jordan, 1993) ibid. Greenwade and Jordan (ibid.) (Gurlami e DeCocco, 1943) ibid. Gurlami e DeCocco (ibid.) (Landa und Schultz, 1943) ebd. Landa und Schultz (ebd.)]